# Java How do I output the initial value of a method's variable before it enters the first recursion of the method?

Tags: java, recursion

Any idea on how to print the initial variable used in the classic factorial recursion?  Here's what I have.

```
public class factorial{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Output:" + initialN(factorial(4))); 
    System.out.println("Answer:24");
  }

  public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 1){
      return 1;
    }
    else{
      return n*(n-1);
    }
  }

  public static int initialN(int n){
    int init = n;
    System.out.println("N:" + init); return init;
  }
}
```

Right now my output looks like this:

```
N:24
Output:24
Answer:24
```

But I'm trying to have it show only what n is initially before it enters the second iteration of the factorial method. So N should be showing as 4, not 24.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you print the initial value and _then_ calculate the factorial?

Comment: Because the initial value is only set once the method is called.  If I try to call the value before the method, it will break because the value doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  If you call the recursion method from a another method, you can print the initial variable.  here is my solution. I'd be interested to see if anyone has a more simple solution.

```
public class factorial{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Output:" + (factorial(3))); System.out.println("Answer:6");
    System.out.println("Output:" + (factorial(4))); System.out.println("Answer:24");
    System.out.print("--------------------");
  }     

  public static int factorial(int n){
    System.out.println("--------------------\nN:" + n);
    return factorial2(n);
  }

  public static int factorial2(int n){
    if(n == 1){
    return 1;
    }
    else{
      return n*factorial2(n-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change this line:

```
System.out.println("Output:" + factorial(initialN(4)));
```

You should call `initialN()` inside factorial because the methods are executed from within and then outward.

As a side note, I would write it like this:

```
public static int factorial3(int num){ 
if(num == 0)
  return 1;
else{
  if(i==0) \\ i is global variable initialized to zero
   System.out.println("N:" + num);
  i++;
  return num * factorial3(num-1);
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
System.out.println(factorial3(4));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured this out on my own. But I did learn something from your response.  Please confirm that when a method is called from inside another, the innermost method is called and then methods are called working outward?  And in the case of a recursion, the recursion completes before moving outward to the next method, correct?

Comment: You are correct. When calling a method inside a method, the innermost method will always be called first. And, in the case of recursion, that is also correct.